# how to mention timer in jmeter run taurus yaml code

Tags: azure, timer, jmeter, azure-pipelines, azure-load-testing

I have added uniform random timer under thread group. I am running load test in azure pipelines. Is there any way that, I can mention that timer in yaml code instead of jmeter script

Timers under jmeter script are not working as expected. So need to check whether they will work properly if mentioned under yaml code in azure pipelines

Answer (score 0):

As of now ([Taurus 1.16.25](https://pypi.org/project/bzt/1.16.25/)) you cannot configure a Timer via YAML, the options are in:

1. [Action Block](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Action-Blocks) which adds a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler, the syntax would be:

   ```
   requests:
   - action: pause
     target: current-thread
     pause-duration: 1s500ms
   ```
2. [JSR223 Blocks](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks) which add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) or [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), you can use arbitrary Groovy code like:

   ```
   requests:
   - url: http://example.com/
     jsr223: 'java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)'
   ```

With regards to "Timers under jmeter script are not working as expected" Timers work as designed, to wit create a pause before each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in their [Scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), it might be the case your "expectations" differ from the actual Timers behaviour. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) for more details if needed.